# How do you use PHP to interact with a running C++ process?

Tags: php, c++

Is it possible to have a C++ program running on a server that sits and waits to be passed arguments by a PHP process. 
The C++ program would then process these arguments and return a result to PHP.

I’ve been searching the web and can see a couple of ways to run a C++ program from PHP but can’t find a way to interact with a C++ program that is already running.

The sort of C++ programs I’m thinking of are ones that might take time to set up e.g. They create a big data structure of some kind and so I don’t want to run them every time I need them. I want the C++ programs to create their data structures and then sit back and wait until asked by PHP for information from that data structure.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you can't store your data structures in a database natively supported by PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use named pipes.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140223054156/http://my.opera.com/zomg/blog/2007/08/29/php-and-named-pipes

and

C++ https://web.archive.org/web/20110926155246/http://ist.marshall.edu/ist480acp/namedpipes.html

Comment: I wrote some tools in C++ and didn't want to convert them, so I used named pipes via PHP in order to communicate! Great solution.

Comment: Thanks everyone, thanks Preet. I've been looking at named pipes and I think they are the way forward for me. My only issue is that when more than one client PHP script instance writes to the named pipe I get problems as I get multiple sets of input and output without knowing what is the correct output for the particular input. Is there a way to only allow one php instance to write to the named pipe at any one time and queue the other instances to wait their turn?

Comment: Depending on the platform you can use Queuing. on Windows there is MS MQ and on linux you have MQSeries. Personally I'd put an identifier on the message (called a correlation id) in the pipe. Then when receiving the message put the messages together based on the id with is unique to the PHP process.

Answer (score 2):

Write a C++ listener that recognizes XML RPC or SOAP requests so it can process the requests natively and return the results to PHP as an XML RPC or SOAP response.

Here are some references:

http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

Answer (score 1):

Would something like SWIG be of use to you? (http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html) You could wrap the functionality you want to use, to expose it to your PHP code.